# API Gateway - GET only works on root not resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, api-gateway

I'm trying to create an API Gateway Lambda. Here's a snippet of my CDK to get an idea of my application:

```js
    const getGenericTournamentsLambdaFn = new lambda.Function(this, 'GetGenericTournamentsLambda', {
      functionName: "GetGenericTournaments",
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../src"),
      handler: "get_generic_tournaments.handler",
      environment: {
      }
    });

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "ATPPredictionsService", {
      restApiName: "ATPPredictionsService",
      description: "Provides APIs for saving and fetching API predictions"
    });


    // works
    api.root.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getGenericTournamentsLambdaFn, {
      requestTemplates: { "text/html": '{ "statusCode": "200"}' }
    }));

   // doesn't work - exact same Lambda!
  const getGenericTournamentsResource = api.root.addResource('getgenerictournaments');
    getGenericTournamentsResource.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getGenericTournamentsLambdaFn, {
      requestTemplates: { "text/html": '{ "statusCode": "200"}' }
    }));
```

I cannot understand why only the root method works while for the other method I get 404. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I've already answered my own question

Comment: No need to close if there is an Answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was due to the handler not pointing to the right endpoint. If you use the route, you need to provide a handler for the resource endpoint. In my case:

```js
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const endpoints = require('./endpoints');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

// must be `/getgenerictournaments` not `/`
app.get('/getgenerictournaments', async (req, res) => {
    endpoints.get_generic_tournaments_handler(req, res);
})

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

exports.handler = (event, context) =>  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```